# error message with IBAction

Tags: swift, xcode, ibaction

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailkeyboard: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordkeyboard: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var myaccountButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var welcomeLabel: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //Built in method
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)

    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        self.emailkeyboard.resignFirstResponder()
        self.passwordkeyboard.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    @IBAction func myaccountbutton(sender: AnyObject) {
        FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithEmail(self.emailField.text!, password: self.passwordField.text!, completion: { (user,error) in

    }

    @IBAction func createaccountButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(emailField.text!, password: passwordField.text!) { (user, error) in
            if error == nil {
                print("User Created")

        if (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser) != nil
        {
            self.myaccountButton.alpha = 1.0
        }
        else
        {
            self.myaccountButton.alpha = 0.0
            self.welcomeLabel.text = ""
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I cant figure out where to put the `)` I asked before but i am still stuck. Sorry guys for asking again. 
I am not sure if theres an error in the code above or with the IBAction itself so I have posted all of the code maybe that will help find the problem.

Comment: Its asking for a ')' next to IBAction func createaccountButton also it says only instance methods can be declared @IBAction

Answer (score 0):

The `signInWithEmail()` function call is missing its ending parentheses, as well as an actual closure for the closure argument.